# Several separate counters jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I need to resolve simple task. I have 5 divs and have 2 buttons for each of them (one will increase the value, 2nd - will decrease). I need to resolve this task via jquery.
The problem is, that all divs have shared counter, I need to create separate for every div. Please advice.

```
<script>
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("body").append(`<div>0</div>`);
    $("div").css({"backgroundColor": "yellow", "width": "100px", "height": "100px", "text-align": "center"});
    $("body").append('<button class="plus" type="button">+</button>');
    $("body").append('<button class="minus" type="button">-</button>');
    $("button").css({"margin-bottom": "20px", "text-align": "center"});

}
let i = 0;
$(".plus").on("click", function () {    
    $(this).prev().text(++i);
});

$(".minus").on("click", function () {
    if (i > 0) {
        $(this).prev().prev().text(--i);
    }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many approaches could be adding a custom **attribute** like `data-counter` to your `div` element. So now each `div` element has a custom data counter that you can increment and decrement. This saves you from the hassle of creating separate variables for each `div` and can be extended to `n` number of divs.

Obviously other approaches do exist which can maybe leverage an array where each index maps with your div and stores the counter for it.

Note - **The source of truth** of this value is now not a js variable but the html itself. So if a person was to inspect the html and change the attribute (`data-counter`) to any other value and if he/she increments or decrements, it will happen on the **updated value**. Similarly he/she can remove the attribute altogether as well and break your client side app for that person (until they reload the page). So keep that in mind. Someone else will definitely post a more JS based data structure approach but I wanted to share this one.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("body").append(`<div data-counter=0>0</div>`);
    $("div").css({"backgroundColor": "yellow", "width": "100px", "height": "100px", "text-align": "center"});
    $("body").append('<button class="plus" type="button">+</button>');
    $("body").append('<button class="minus" type="button">-</button>');
    $("button").css({"margin-bottom": "20px", "text-align": "center"});

}
$(".plus").on("click", function () {   
    var counter = $(this).prev().attr('data-counter');
    $(this).prev().text(++counter);
    $(this).prev().attr('data-counter',counter);
});

$(".minus").on("click", function () {
    var counter = $(this).prev().prev().attr('data-counter');
    if (counter > 0) {
    $(this).prev().prev().text(--counter);
    $(this).prev().prev().attr('data-counter',counter);
    }
});
</script>
```